# Set dependent property variable with custom setter method for object in Swift

Tags: swift, object, properties, getter-setter

I have a class object property named object, and **a boolean readonly variable named isEmpty**. If the object property is set to some object, the isEmpty property is switched to false, and if the object is set as nil, isEmpty is set as true. I can achieve this using Objective-C as following:

```
@interface SomeObject: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) id object;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) BOOL isEmpty;

@end

@implementation SomeObject

- (void)object:(id)object {
    _isEmpty = NO;
    _object = object;
}

- (id)object {
    return _object;
}

- (void)clearObject {
    _object = nil;
    _isEmpty = YES;
}

@end
```

How can I imitate this in Swift 2.2? So far I have tried

```
class SomeObject: NSObject {
   public private(set) var isEmpty: Bool
   var nodeObject: AnyObject? = {
        get {
           isEmpty = false
           return object
        }
        set(_object: AnyObject) {
            object = _object
        }
    }
}
```

But it is not working, as expected! I know it is wrong, but not sure about which part!

TIA

Comment: Make `nodeObject` an *optional* and remove the other stuff ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have an absolute requirement to set isEmpty, I would go about it this way: create a getter for isEmpty and check whether nodeObject is null in the getter:

```
class SomeObject {
  var isEmpty: Bool {
    get {
       return nodeObject == nil
    }
  }
  var nodeObject: AnyObject?
}
```

See fiddle: http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57c73513458cfba6715ebebd

EDIT: If you really want to get it close to Objective-C, I suggest this version:

```
class SomeObject {
   private var _isEmpty: Bool = true
   var isEmpty: Bool {
       get {
           return _isEmpty
       }
   }
   var nodeObject: AnyObject? {
       didSet {
            _isEmpty = nodeObject == nil
       }
   }
}
```

Fiddle: https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57c738b646a02c0452203f98

Comment: Better idea, many thanks! But the isEmpty should be a readonly property.

Comment: @Shahib, isEmpty is readonly in my example (there is no setter). However, in yours it's read/write.

Comment: Sorry about the typo, I have updated the question. I thought, the Objective-C example would make it clear. Anyway, thanks man!

Comment: I have accepted your answer. The first one you provided with fiddle is much cleaner than I was anticipating! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

would this work for you?:

```
class SomeObject: NSObject {
    var isEmpty: Bool
    var nodeObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            if nodeObject != nil {
                isEmpty = false
            } else {
                isEmpty = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the **SWIFT 2** version:

```
class SomeObject: NSObject {
    var object: AnyObject? {
        return object
    }
    private(set) var isEmpty = false


    func object(object: AnyObject) {
        self.isEmpty = false
        self.object = object!
    }

    func clearObject() {
        self.object = nil
        self.isEmpty = true
    }
}
```